# OpenOffice oocalc Add Password Command Line

Tags: password-protection, openoffice-calc

I want to add passwords to about 65,000 excel spreadsheets. I have OpenOffice oocalc. I can open a spreadsheet, click save as, select add password, enter a password, and save the file over itself. That manual solution will not work. I need to script this. I've found answers for "how do I remove a password on the command line?" I have not been able to find any answers for "how do I add a password on the command line?" Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First create a property with the [password](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/MediaDescriptor.html#Password).  Then [store the document](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XStorable.html#storeAsURL), passing the property as an argument.  See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=48432.

Detailed, related code is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=66515.  It sounds like you may have already seen this link, so hopefully it will be clear when you use the information in my first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. Those solutions require tackling an even more difficult problem: Getting Redhat's Python to use the uno library. I've tried many "solutions" to that problem, but nothing has worked - unless getting the library not found error is your goal.

Comment: To avoid the library issue, you could write the code in Basic.

Comment: First, this is a Redhat server, so VB is out. Second, the goal is to have a command-line-only program to run that encrypts an xlsx file. Assuming that I am able to write a basic script on Redhat, can I write one that does not need to have OpenOffice running and is 100% command-line-only?

Comment: To invoke a Basic (not VB) macro, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/how-to-invoke-an-openoffice-macro-from-the-linux-command-line.